# Mixing cookies and css with php

Tags: php, html, css, cookies

So I have really simple css file that is generated based on cookie that is fetched using php. Whole css is also displayed using php so it

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css");
$rand = $_COOKIE['randTopic'];

echo '
body {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    background: none;
}

.full {
  background: url("http://loremflickr.com/1920/1080/' . $rand . '") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  }
';
?>
```

Loremflickr is just a service that gives me random image from flickr, I can also choose topic what I am doing actually. So the output css looks exactly like this:

```
body {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    background: none;
}

.full {
  background: url("http://loremflickr.com/1920/1080/wall
") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  }
```

As you can see there's a linebreak that I didn't really want, no idea why it's here. I think it could cause the problem, what do you think?

Thank you kindly in advance for any help.

Comment: If there is a line break in your cookie, then it'll cause a line break, double check that to ensure you don't have one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick fix for that is to use `trim()` function on data from cookie.

But first of all I would check why is there line break. Inspect your code.

Comment: trim works as supposed, thanks, problem solved. The case is that linebreak appeared from the middle of nowhere. I did check on that before posting my question. The actual cookie content is: "spinach%0A" so it has linebreak on it which I didn't add when putting this in my cookie. Really strange, I think I'll just stick to trim...

Answer (score 1):

[`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) the variable in your output -

```
echo '
....
background: url("http://loremflickr.com/1920/1080/' . trim($rand) . '") no-repeat center center fixed;
....
';
```

Comment: Ah, the timestamp ;-) [era primo](https://translate.google.ca/?hl=en&tab=wT#it/en/era%20primo)